# how to solve problem of curlexception 6: name lookup time out error in facebook new graph api

Tags: php, facebook

Hi I m creating application on facebook using new graph api but it gives error as

curlexception 6: name lookup time out in facebook.php file.

The problem is that same code is works fine on other server and not gives this error. How to solve this error Please help me.

Comment: This seems to explain what's going on: http://digitalmemo.neobie.net/2010/08/23/solving-uncaught-curlexception-name-lookup-timed-out-in-facebook-php/

Comment: thanks for replying. I already tried it but it's still not working. Please give other solution.

Comment: Where are you hosting your facebook app?  If you're increasing your Curl timeout value and you're still facing troubles, you may want to switch hosting providers.  Also, are you using the latest facebook sdk?  They regularly update it with bug fixes.

Answer (score 11):

I had this same problem when developing locally on a virtual machine. I solved it by upping my Curl Connect Timeout.

Look for `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT = 10` in your facebook SDK. Try changing it to `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT = 30` or `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT = 60`

Answer (score 3):

Update: form Facebook SDK 3.x the CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT is located in the file **base_facebook.php** not in the facebook.php.

I believe you can also change the value dynamically as the CURL_OPTS are send every makeRequest (please edit if this is not the case!):

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
       'appId' => $your['AppId'],
       'secret' => $your['AppSecret'],
       'cookie' => true
));

$facebook->CURL_OPTS['CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT'] = 30;
```

See also: [SSL Connection timeout in facebook fql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307322/ssl-connection-timeout-in-facebook-fql) for other timeout issues :D

Answer (score 0):

just go to base_facebook.php SDK liberary file and increase the value of CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10 to 60 all is done...