# SSL Connection timeout in facebook fql

Tags: php, facebook, ssl, facebook-fql

I am using facebook api to get backup of the facebook photos using access_token and fql.

Using fql I got the list of albums of the user

```
$client = new Facebook(array('appId' => 'xxxx', 'secret' => 'xxxxxx'));
$fql_albums = "SELECT aid,name from album where owner=$user_Id";

$albumId = $client->api(array(
    'method'       => 'fql.query',
    'access_token' => $user_access_token,
    'query'        => $fql_albums,
));
```

After getting this list I run a query to get all the photos in the album and then download that album and then moves to the next album.

It only download 2 albums and then gets an error as shown below

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 28: SSL connection timeout
>   thrown in
>   D:\wamp\www\FrostBox1.0\Facebook\FaceBookConnect\facebook-php-sdk\src\base_facebook.php
>   on line 759

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. open `base_facebook.php`
2. find `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10`
3. change it to `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30`

That's it!

Answer (score 18):

For me, the solution was adding

```
$opts[CURLOPT_SSLVERSION] = 3;
```

before

```
curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);
```

in base_facebook.php

Thanks to:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/213367445404472/?browse=search_4eeccca164bbe6357503363

Comment: This answer fixed it for me too! I think some versions of libcurl don't activate SSLv3 by default

Comment: This fixed it for me as well, after much debugging and even contacting our web host and having them update and reinstall the latest (patched version) of Apache with OpenSSL. Thanks

Comment: set this option even if curl debug says it is already using version 3, a little bug maybe, specifically setting to version 3 this sorted it out for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding:

```
CURLOPT_SSLVERSION     => 3,
```

after the line:

```
CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'facebook-php-3.1',
```

at - `base_facebook.php`

(it will make curl to use `SSLv3`)