# SSL timeouts and "Unknown SSL protocol" errors

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

Using PHP SDK v3.1.1, I'm experiencing SSL errors that are slows down my app (high traffic) significantly for  the last 4-5 days:

```
"CurlException: 28: SSL connection timeout"
"CurlException: 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to graph.facebook.com:443"
"CurlException: 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api-read.facebook.com:443"
```

I saw other people having these issues, so I think it may be on Facebook's side and not mine?

Thanks in advance,
Bar.

Comment: Sounds like problems at FB's end to me. All of those messages indicate socket-level errors, over which cURL gives you no (or very little) control.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, did following for fix after digging in github:

```
//in your facebook.php file, avoid ssl verification
$opts[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false; //add after $opts[CURLOPT_URL] = $url;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Turning off SSL verification is a very bad idea. Try the solution here first: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9915635/109611