# using the new facebook payments reports API

Tags: php, facebook

been trying to get data from the facebook payments reports API, since they say on november 7th no more reports will be sent by email.
tried php and got an error - "SSL connection timeout".
this is the php curl code i'm using:

```
$set_action_url = "https://paymentreports.facebook.com/".$company_id."/report?date=".$date."&type=".$type."&access_token=".$company_token;
$ch = curl_init($set_action_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

i logged the url and query string just before the call, and if i use it in a browser
i do get the file.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSL Connection timeout in facebook fql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307322/ssl-connection-timeout-in-facebook-fql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
```

Comment: Could someone please post a code sample of how to work with the response coming from this API? is there some documentation about it? facebook's documentation is so vague... basically, when i'm logging the response it looks like a string, within there's a lot of "junk" characters, and the name of the file - don't know how to get my data!?  please help,  thanks

Comment: @user1750618 you should better [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead. With code sample, etc ..

Answer (score 0):

to fetch the zip file, file_get_contents also works